# Upload ByteArray to server - With upload progress

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, file-upload, arrays

Is it possible that I can upload a `ByteArray` and receive a `ProgressEvent` on the **upload**   progress?

I have tried:

- Using `URLLoader`, but then I realized that it only shows the progress for the download.
- Using `FileReference`, but then I realized that `FileReference.data` is read only.

Is there any way I can do this?

The user records with their microphone, and the sound is then uploaded to the server. This is why it's a `ByteArray` and not a `FileReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of searching around and came on a couple other SO posts that seem to indicate it is not possible.  If you're using AIR perhaps you could save the ByteArray to a file using FileStream then load that file into a File object and call upload() on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can to this only via self programming.
make and uploader server side script java for ex. and send the progress percentage via socket 
so flash sending file and receiving the progress data via socket.